# Making an android a a2dp sink, or a pass-though music player with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

So firstly, although this has been asked before, have there been any recent updates that allow you to change a device to an a2dp sink instead of source from the app level?

What I want, is to create an app that can be on two phones. One phone has music, and via bluetooth is streaming that to the phone, which in turn is sending that to a bluetooth speaker. To clarify, the second phone is not playing music, merely passing it on to the speaker.

Like this

|Device 1| --bluetooth music stream--> |Device 2| --> |Bluetooth speaker|

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you cannot. To stream audio to Bluetooth device it should support A2DP profile. But none of the phones are designed with A2DP.